# Trying to override CSS... but its in a PHP iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am wishing to inject/ override some CSS code in the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    feed2js_ck = true;

    document.write('<div class="rss-box" style="color: #414141; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font- 
    size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">');
    document.write('<p class="rss-item"><br />');
    document.write('<span class="rss-date" >All systems are operational at this time.</span>');
    document.write('</p>');
    document.write('</div>');
    </script>
```

I currently have the following:

```
    var style = document.createElement( 'link' );
    style.rel = 'stylesheet';
    style.type = 'text/javascript';
    style.href = chrome.extension.getURL( '/themes/darkTheme/status.php' );
    ( document.head || document.documentElement ).appendChild( style );
    var logoURL = chrome.extension.getURL( "/status.php" );
```

however, it is not currently working... i am thinking i am going about this the wrong way, I apologize for the issue.

Much help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain in your post what the expected behaviour should be? And could you also post the contents of `status.php`?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer the CSS part of your question without understanding better what it is you are trying to achieve. I will extend this answer when I have a clearer idea of what your CSS objective is.

In the meantime, if you can possibly avoid it, you really shouldn't be using document.write in your javascript - it's a very old approach, it's not performant and it throws up  all sorts of problems.

Instead, you can build a `DocumentFragment` and attach that to your document:

```
// CREATE THE FRAGMENT
let rssFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

// CREATE .rss-box
let rssBox = document.createElement('div');
rssBox.classList.add('rss-box');

// CREATE .rss-item
let rssItem = document.createElement('p');
rssItem.classList.add('rss-item');

// CREATE .rss-date
let rssDate = document.createElement('span');
rssDate.classList.add('rss-date');
rssDate.textContent = 'All systems are operational at this time.'

// BUILD THE FRAGMENT
rssItem.appendChild(rssDate); // Puts rssDate into rssItem
rssBox.appendChild(rssItem); // Puts rssItem into rssBox
rssFragment.appendChild(rssBox); // Puts rssBox into rssFragment

// ADD THE FRAGMENT TO THE DOCUMENT
document.body.appendChild(rssFragment);
```